# MYSQL Audit Trail

Tags: mysql, audit-trail

Hello I use the following way to use an audit trail:

First a user log into a database with the following procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `oms_Insert_AuditTrailLogin`(
    IN `EmployeeRefID` BIGINT,
    IN `IPAdress` VARCHAR(50),
    IN `LoginTime` DATETIME
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
BEGIN
   SET @EmployeeID = EmployeeRefID;

    INSERT INTO omsdb.tbl_data_AuditTrailLogin
   (EmployeeRefID, IPAdress, LoginTime)
   VALUES
   (EmployeeRefID, IPAdress, LoginTime);

   SELECT Last_Insert_ID() AS ID;
END
```

I need the variable @EmployeeID to identify the user.

After update trigger:

...

```
INSERT INTO omsdb.tbl_data_AuditTrail 
(evType, Tablename, DatabaseName, PrimaryKey, UpdateDate, @EmployeeID) 
VALUES 
('UPDATE', 'tbl_data_bcrabl', 'molbiolabdb', @Pk, NOW(), @EmployeeID); 

SET @AuditTrailRefID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 

IF NEW.bcrabl != OLD.bcrabl OR OLD.bcrabl IS NULL THEN INSERT INTO omsdb.tbl_data_AuditTrailData 
(AuditTrailRefID, FieldName, OldValue, NewValue) 
VALUES 
(@AuditTrailRefID, 'bcrabl', OLD.bcrabl, NEW.bcrabl); 
END IF; 
...
```

the after update trigger works fine but the @EmployeeID has no value - it's always "NULL"
How could I create variables outside a trigger and use this information in the trigger
to identify the user? I could not use the function USER() etc.

Thank you very much

Elmar

Comment: This is not a trigger but a part of it only. There is no info what table this trigger is defined on, what is the structure of this table, what action fires this trigger..

Comment: *How could I create variables outside a trigger and use this information in the trigger* In the trigger you can easily use user-defined variables which are set before **in the same session**.

Comment: I know it is'nt the whole trigger but if the user log in the ID of the user is stored in the @employeeid. "... which are set before in the same session" - so it it impossible to solve my problem? After call the oms_Insert_AuditTrailLogin() procedure I could not use the user-defined variables because it is the same session?

Comment: In my comment "session" == "definite connection to MySQL". If you close the connection where the variable was set then this variable value is lost. It the connection was failed and (auto-)restored then the variable value is lost. Store your data in some static object (service table, for example).